RoomCaptureSession persistence, ARSession pause broken?
Our app allows a user to scan a room and then save that scan on a separate view, followed by additional scans. We're looking into allowing room combining via CapturedStructure, so we need rooms to be scanned in the same ARWorldMap without necessarily needing to re-localize in the same app session. This should fit within the first scenario that Apple described.
The only way I have found that allows our requirements is to save RoomCaptureView and to re-use that RoomCaptureView whenever we need to start a session again. This creates a number of other issues, and ideally, we wouldn't need to save a View in something like a singleton. We are using captureSession.stop(pauseARSession: false). Additionally, if we use the same RoomCaptureView and an error occurs during the scanning process, we can't get the instructions overlay to appear again if we reuse this view (specifically, the instructions in the middle of the view that state "Move device to start"). It's as if the instructions are completely removed and scanning is stuck on an error state if an error occurs.
These instructions also seem to be separate from the instructions we can grab from RoomCaptureViewDelegate via didProvide instruction: RoomCaptureSession.Instruction, so we can't use that either. There's a couple subviews that seem relevant to this: RoomCaptureCoachingOverlayView and ARGlyphView - but both are not public, so we can't force them to appear. Also attempted a number of other things to try to get these subviews to appear, such as layoutIfNeeded().
Saving the ARSession and using it in let roomCaptureView = RoomCaptureView(frame: viewBounds, arSession: arSession) where we're creating a new view with the same ARSession seems much more ideal as that solves the above issues, but we run into another issue: world tracking seems to be completely lost when a new RoomCaptureView (and thus a new RoomCaptureSession) is started, even with the same already started ARSession, almost as if captureSession.stop(pauseARSession: false) doesn't work as described.
Is there any way around needing to use the same RoomCaptureView or RoomCaptureSession for subsequent scans in the same session without needing to re-localize via ARWorldMap loading? Is there a way to force the guiding instructions to appear?
